# How to reduce column gaps in yii/bootsrap/activeform (Yii2)?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I am using yii/bootrap/active form and I set the layout to Horizontal
How can I reduce a gap between two columns ? I mean, where is the CSS file in yii/bootrap/activeform ?

My view code is like this

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
use yii\helpers\BaseHtml;
use app\assets\myassets\InputAsset;
?>
<?php
$listData = ['1' => 'Ya', '0' => 'Tidak'];
$button = Html::button('Cancel', ['class' => 'btn btn-default btn-md', 'data' => ['dismiss' => "modal"]]);
$button .= Html::button('Submit', ['id' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-success success btn-md']);
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h2>Konfirmasi</h2>',
    'toggleButton' => false,
    'id' => 'confirm-submit',
    'footer' => $button
    ]);
    echo 'Data ini akan disimpan ?';
Modal::end();
?>

<div class="jenis-form">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
    'id' => 'marketing',
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
        'label' => 'col-sm-2',
        'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-2',
        'wrapper' => 'col-sm-4',
    ],
],
]); 
?>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'jn_byr')->textInput(['readonly' => !$model->isNewRecord,'autofocus'=>$model->isNewRecord,]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'nama')->textInput(['autofocus'=>!$model->isNewRecord,]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'ket_dnd')->textInput() ?> 
        <?= $form->field($model, 'ket_bat')->textInput() ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'ket_tts')->textInput() ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'k_inv')->textInput() ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'ket_battg')->textInput() ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'ketkw')->textInput() ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'ketrk')->textInput() ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'tagih[]')->dropDownList($listData,['prompt'=>'<<< Pilih >>>']); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'deposit')->dropDownList($listData,['prompt'=>'<<< Pilih >>>']); ?>
    </div>
</div>      
<div>
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: you can find it by inspect element

Comment: and I would suggest to override them by your own css, dont edit core files

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I better make my own CSS.

Comment: Use your own css and overwrite class that you need to change. It's only good solutions